# Eliminate space at end of list in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, minipage

I have a `tabular` environment, created with `array` loaded and using `m` columns, the cells of which mostly contain lists.  In cells with a list, there is about 1em of dead space at the end of the list before the bottom of the cell (in the cell with the largest contents which sets the row size).  I am trying to get rid of this space, to no avail.  I am using a custom `itemize*` environment that sets `\topsep`, `\parskip`, and `\partopsep` all to 0pt at the beginning (immediately after `\begin{itemize}`).  This eliminates internal spacing but not the end spacing.  I also have it setting `\@noparlisttrue`, but to no avail.  Here's my `itemize*` definition:

```
\newenvironment{itemize*}{\begin{itemize}%
  \setlength\topsep{0pt}%
  \setlength\itemsep{-2pt}%
  \setlength\parskip{0pt}%
  \setlength\partopsep{0pt}%
  \@noparlisttrue}{\end{itemize}}
```

I've tried setting `\topsep`, `\parskip`, and `\partopsep` before the `\begin{itemize*}` in my table cell as well, but I *still* have the blank space.

Tracing and Phillipe's comment indicate that it is invoking `\par` at the end of the list and this is causing the whitespace.  Including `\setlength\parskip{0pt}` or `\setlength\parskip{-\baselineskip}` before `\begin{itemize*}` or before `\end{itemize*}` do not eliminate the space.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You may want to try loading the `enumerate` package and using the `compactenum` environment, rather than `itemize`. With `compactenum`, you have to define your item label by passing an optional argument at the beginning of the environment declaration. `compactenum` nicely takes care of unnecessary dead space. Does this work for you?

Comment: your `\setlength\topsep` has no effect where it is placed, but that's not the problem here. In fact, `\end{itemize}` calls a `\par` and that's what is causing the blank line. Even a simple code as `\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}text\par\end{tabular}` has the problem, so it doesn't seem to be a list problem at all.

Comment: @Philippe I had suspected that the `\par` was the issue.  I'd tried to suppress `\par` with the `\@noparlisttrue`, but there was still one `\par` emitted.  How can I suppress `\par`'s whitespace? Putting `\setlength\parskip{0pt}` before `\begin` or right before `\end` don't do it.

Comment: @Jimi: you probably mean `paralist` and `compactitem`.

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, indeed, I meant `paralist`! Funny enough, I've always used `compactenum`, though. That's why I've always had to specify my item label. But, yes, `compactitem` does the job even better, since it automatically includes the bullets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could avoid that additional space by putting the `itemize*` environment into a `\parbox`, even if it's already in a `p` cell. A `minipage` would also work.

Such a `minipage` environment could also be inserted into your definition of `\itemize*`. However, a width is mandatory. If the width is variable, it might mean additional work.

If you need a quick fix: `\vspace{-2em}` or any other suitable negative value, directly after `\end{itemize}` in your definition, would remove empty space at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  This does yield some more confusion, as the `m` and `p` styles are documented as being (roughly) equivalent to a `\parbox`, but this must be a piece excluded by 'roughly equivalent'?

Comment: @Michael: yes, it is. It's funny that a `\parbox` within a `p`-cell does it. One could use it work out another fix for space problem, for me the night is just half over...